# I want to have all results for content spinning

Tags: php

[The outcome I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k2bH.jpg)

[The outcome I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKcNj.jpg)

I'm stuck with my script.

I would like this script to display all possible results when I run it.
Unfortunately, I can't find the function that will allow me to display all the results in my browser.
When I launch it, it displays a single result, which changes each time I refresh.

Does anyone have a track?

```
<?php
class Spintax
{
    public function process($text)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback(
            '/\{(((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*)\}/x',
            array($this, 'replace'),
            $text
        );
    }
    public function replace($text)
    {
        $text = $this->process($text[1]);
        $parts = explode('|', $text);
        return $parts[array_rand($parts)];
    }
}



/* EXAMPLE USAGE */ 
$spintax = new Spintax();


$string = '{Hello|Howdy|Hola} to you, {Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.} {Smith|Williams|Davis}!';
echo $spintax->process($string);
```

Comment: _display all possible results_? Please show us the current outcome, vs. expected outcome.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. I updated my post with 2 screenshots (i've made the outcome wanted with Word)

Comment: @Miamdeschips don't forget to also up vote the answers that helped you :) This way you help to keep the community supporting you stronger ! :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible alternative:

```
<?php
class Spintax
{
    public function process($text)
    {
        preg_match_all('/(\{[^\}]+\})/', $text, $matches);
        $sets = [];

        foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
            $sets[$match]['replacements'] = explode('|',
                str_replace(
                    ['{', '}'],
                    '',
                    $match
                )
            );
            $sets[$match]['results'] = [];
        }

        foreach($sets as $placeholder => $entries) {
            $replacements = $entries['replacements'];

            foreach($replacements as $replace) {
                $sets[$placeholder]['results'][] = str_replace(
                    $placeholder,
                    $replace,
                    $text
                );

                foreach($sets as $innerPlaceholder => $innerEntries) {
                    $innerResults = $innerEntries['results'];
                    
                    foreach($innerResults as $result) {
                        $sets[$placeholder]['results'][] = str_replace(
                            $placeholder,
                            $replace,
                            $result
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $output = array_unique($sets[array_key_last($sets)]['results']);
        return array_values(
                array_filter(
                $output,
                function($entry) {
                    return 0 === preg_match('/\{[^\}]+\}/', $entry);
                }
            )
        );
    }
}



/* EXAMPLE USAGE */ 
$spintax = new Spintax();


$string = '{Hello|Howdy|Hola} to you, {Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.} {Smith|Williams|Davis}!';
print_r( $spintax->process($string) );
```

My result is like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello to you, Mr. Smith!
    [1] => Howdy to you, Mr. Smith!
    [2] => Hola to you, Mr. Smith!
    [3] => Hello to you, Mrs. Smith!
    [4] => Howdy to you, Mrs. Smith!
    [5] => Hola to you, Mrs. Smith!
    [6] => Hello to you, Ms. Smith!
    [7] => Howdy to you, Ms. Smith!
    [8] => Hola to you, Ms. Smith!
    [9] => Hello to you, Mr. Williams!
    [10] => Howdy to you, Mr. Williams!
    [11] => Hola to you, Mr. Williams!
    [12] => Hello to you, Mrs. Williams!
    [13] => Howdy to you, Mrs. Williams!
    [14] => Hola to you, Mrs. Williams!
    [15] => Hello to you, Ms. Williams!
    [16] => Howdy to you, Ms. Williams!
    [17] => Hola to you, Ms. Williams!
    [18] => Hello to you, Mr. Davis!
    [19] => Howdy to you, Mr. Davis!
    [20] => Hola to you, Mr. Davis!
    [21] => Hello to you, Mrs. Davis!
    [22] => Howdy to you, Mrs. Davis!
    [23] => Hola to you, Mrs. Davis!
    [24] => Hello to you, Ms. Davis!
    [25] => Howdy to you, Ms. Davis!
    [26] => Hola to you, Ms. Davis!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
class Spintax
{
    private $counter = 0;
    private $options = [];

    public function process($text)
    {
        $template = preg_replace_callback(
            '/\{(((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*)\}/x',
            array($this, 'replace'),
            $text
        );

        $combinations = [[]];

        foreach ($this->options as $i => $list) {
            $new_combinations = [];
            $key = '{' . ($i + 1) . '}';

            foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
                foreach ($list as $item) {
                    $combination[$key] = $item;
                    $new_combinations[] = $combination;
                }
            }

            $combinations = $new_combinations;
        }

        $result = [];
        foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
            $result[] = strtr($template, $combination);
        }

        return $result;
    }
    public function replace($text)
    {
        ++$this->counter;
        $this->options[] = explode('|', $text[1]);
        return '{' . $this->counter . '}';
    }
}

$spintax = new Spintax();

$string = '{Hello|Howdy|Hola} to you, {Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.} {Smith|Williams|Davis}!';
$result = $spintax->process($string);
echo implode("\n", $result);
```

Brief explanation:

Function `process()` saves all possible alternatives into `$options` property, and transforms the string into template like `{1} to you, {2} {3}!`. Then it generates all possible combinations of the collected options and then generates all the results by substituting every combination into the template string.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much, you are so helpful !

Comment: Welcome @Miamdeschips :) Don't forget to mark this answer as solution